# detect if user clicked on add to home screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

with javascript or jQuery, is there a way to detect if the user added my site to his home screen in mobile browsers?

i want to detect it at the second he hit on 'add to home screen'

Comment: Try google analytics..pass referral parameter in URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
if(isMobile.any()) {
   alert("This is a Mobile Device");
}
```

And then

```
$("#btn-id").on('click',function(){
  //Write code to get msg
)};
```

Comment: thanks! @RobAu for showing me how to post an aswer to query

Answer (score 0):

Mmm this should be part of the browser's functionality and is not likely to be exposed to the js on a particular page.

So ... I think you cannot do in within the page.